# Java : Does Locale affect the Formatter for JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, locale, customization, jformattedtextfield

I have created a custom component (NumberFormattedTextField) of JFormattedTextField. This is the Formatter I use :

```
    public static InternationalFormatter getDecimalIFormatter92() {
    // For Buy & Sale Price
    DecimalFormat numberFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance();
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);

    final InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(numberFormat);
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    formatter.setMinimum(0.00);
    formatter.setMaximum(999999999.99);

    return formatter;
}
```

When I create an instance of NumberFormattedTextField :

```
 public RelationsPanel(CashParent parent) {
    try {
    initComponents();   // startBalTxt = new NumberFormattedTextField();
    Utility.logInfo("initComponents OVER");
    myParent = parent;
    nameTxt.setSizeLimit(20);
    System.out.println("startBalTxt.setFormatter GOING FOR IT"); 
    this.startBalTxt.setFormatter(Utility.getDecimalIFormatter82());  // Must be throwing here
    System.out.println("startBalTxt.setFormatter DONE"); 
    this.currentBalTxt.setFormatter(Utility.getDecimalIFormatter82());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utility.logInfo("Failed to Initialize : " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

NumberFormattedTextField CLASS Code :

```
public class NumberFormattedTextField extends JFormattedTextField implements java.io.Serializable, DocumentListener, FocusListener {
private DecimalFormat numberFormat;
private InternationalFormatter formatter;
private double MAX_VALUE = 999999.99;
private final Map attributes = (Utility.getTextFont()).getAttributes();

/**
 * Creates a NumberFormattedTextField with 6 Integer & 2 Fractional digits.
 * Minimum is set to 0.00 and Max to 999999.99 without any grouping used.
 */
public NumberFormattedTextField() {
    super();
    createFormatter();  // Creates a default formatter, used if formatter is not set
    this.setValue(0.00);
    init();
}


private void createFormatter() {
    // Create standard DecimalFormat
    numberFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance();
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);

    formatter = new InternationalFormatter(numberFormat);
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    formatter.setMinimum(0.00);
    formatter.setMaximum(999999.99);

    this.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactoryImpl());
}

private void init() {
    setFont(Utility.getTextFont());
    this.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    this.addFocusListener(this);
    attributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON);
    setFocusLostBehavior(PERSIST);
}

public void setFormatter(InternationalFormatter format) {
    super.setFormatter(format);
    System.out.println("Class of Format = " + format.getFormat().getClass());
    if (format.getFormat() instanceof java.text.DecimalFormat)
        numberFormat = (DecimalFormat)format.getFormat();
    else
        numberFormat = (DecimalFormat)(NumberFormat) format.getFormat();

    formatter = format;
    // AbstractFormatterFactoryImpl returns formatter straight away    
    this.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactoryImpl());
    calculateMaxValue();
}

private void calculateMaxValue() {
    try {
        if (formatter.getMaximum() != null) {
            //System.out.println(" MAX ALlowed = " + formatter.getMaximum());
            String no = formatter.valueToString(formatter.getMaximum());
            char seperator = java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getGroupingSeparator();
            no = no.replace(String.valueOf(seperator), "");
            System.out.println("MAX Number to PArse = " + no);
            MAX_VALUE = Double.parseDouble(no);  // HERE ITS THROWING EXCEPTION
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NumberFormattedTextField.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The above code on my PC works perfectly well. But on client's PC it gives error :
 Failed to Initialize : For input string: "99999999,99"
ERROR/Logs that I GET :

```
      startBalTxt.setFormatter GOING FOR IT
  INFO: initComponents OVER
  Class of Format = class java.text.DecimalFormat
  MAX Number to PArse = 99999999,99
  INFO: Failed to Initialize : For input string: "99999999,99"
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "99999999,99"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at cashaccountingapp.components.NumberFormattedTextField.calculateMaxValue(NumberFormattedTextField.java:184)
 Class of Format = class java.text.DecimalFormat
    at cashaccountingapp.components.NumberFormattedTextField.setFormatter(NumberFormattedTextField.java:173)
    at cashaccountingapp.data.RelationsPanel.<init>(RelationsPanel.java:35)
```

The locale of both of us are different.

What can be the reason for this error ? Different Locale or something else that I need to take care in my NumberFormattedTextField class. I want app to adapt the system settings and show accordingly.

How to handle out the problem ??

Comment: kleapatra is right. The MAX_VALUE = Double.parseDouble(no); line in calculateMaxValue() is throwing the exception. Have added exception also in the code. The String has a valid value just instead of "." it has "," for decimal seperator- that too due to locale. So I guess now the point should be "HOW to parse the String to a double with such Locale". Any IDEAS, Suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution :

I get the DecimalFormatSymbols instance of Locale.US specifically. This helps me get the string in standard format with proper decimal seperator. And thus am able to parse the valid string to Double.
Here is the code I changed, if at all it may help any body :

```
    private void calculateMaxValue() {
    try {
        if (formatter.getMaximum() != null) {
            String no = formatter.valueToString(formatter.getMaximum());
            // Get DecimalFormatSymbols instance of Locale.US
            char seperator = java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(java.util.Locale.US).getGroupingSeparator();
            no = no.replace(String.valueOf(seperator), "");
            MAX_VALUE = Double.parseDouble(no);
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Utility.logs.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

That's it, no other changes were required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

most probably (can't be entirely sure, as you don't show the intial setting and crippled the error to its message only ;-) different Locales are the reason: one has the period as decimal point, the other has the comma. So if you initialize the one with a String representing the number in the other, it will clash: the comma is not interpreted as a decimal separator, so the max is too big to fit the limits

Comment: "initial settings" - I think you are referring to initialization of NumberFormattedTextField. Have added constructor and more code of that class. I agree with your point for decimal seperator. How to handle this with different locales? Can this be for setMaximum(999999999.99); line too. For String representing the number, am taking seperator using DecimalSymbols - so wouldn't that provide me the default locale's seperator ?

Comment: yes you are right. The MAX_VALUE = Double.parseDouble(no); line in calculateMaxValue() is throwing the exception. Have added exception also in the code. The String has avalid value just instead of "." it has "," for decimal seperator- that too due to locale. So I guess now the point should be "HOW to parse the String to a double with such Locale". Any IDEAS, Suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

After two hours of googling and making some changes, I get a simpler solution, to accept only dot(.) as decimal separator in a `JFormattedTextField`:

```
JFormattedTextField txtTax = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
txtTax.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new NumberFormatter(new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("us", "EN"))))));
```

This solution ignores System `locale(ec,ES)` and sets the component a specific locale (us,EN)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. In my solution I have used DecimalFormatsymbols with US Locale for setting my formatter.